# Continue Execution of records after one record fails in JBehave story

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, jbehave

If one of the n records of a story fails, the other records should execute successfully.

```
Scenario: Create a story 
Given I login with <username> and <password>

Examples:
username|password|
abc|123|
def|1234|
```

If first record fails, second record should execute properly

What happens is that if one record fails , other records don't execute .

If one of the n records fail , others should execute properly

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can do it in more clear way and with the way it will be clear for other users of the story.

```
 Scenario1
    Given user with username and password
    When you try to login
    Then login should fail
  Scenario2  
    Given user with username and password
    When you try to login
    Then login should be successful
```